# How do I generate separate html reports using parallel cucumber where only the result of last executed scenario is stored

Tags: ruby, parallel-processing, cucumber, capybara

I'm looking for individual html report for the scenarios I execute using parallel cucumber. I used:

```
gem install parallel_cucumber
```

Then executed:

```
parallel_cucumber -n 4 -o "-f pretty -f html -o report.html" features/*.feature
```

But when I use the above statement to execute the report is overridden and only the results of last executed scenario is stored. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As documented on the gems github page - https://github.com/bayandin/parallel_cucumber#reports - don't specify the output file in the cucumber options, specify it in the config/cucumber.yaml file and include the process number in the name

Comment: I just got this line .  --format html --out report<%= ENV['TEST_ENV_NUMBER'] %>.html. So do u mean to say instead of 'TEST_ENV_NUMBER' i need to input process number. IF yes, may I know from where can i get the number. Sorry. I'm new in using this option

Comment: @RPD As the section I linked to shows parallel_cucumber sets the environment variable TEST_PROCESS_NUMBER not TEST_ENV_NUMBER, so in the parallel_reports section of cucumber.yaml  you would need `--format html --out report<%= ENV['TEST_PROCESS_NUMBER'].html` if you aren't willing to just copy what it shows.  Then just execute `parallel_cucumber -n 4  features/*.feature`

Comment: @ Tom Walpole : Thanks I copy pasted the line. --format html --out report<%= ENV['TEST_PROCESS_NUMBER'].html  . I have a doubt here. Should I need to input a value for "TEST_PROCESS_NUMBER"? Or just copy pasting is enough

Comment: @RPD I believe it should be automatically set, and the %> appears to be missing

Comment: A quick search of the code shows it's set by parallel_cucumber here - https://github.com/bayandin/parallel_cucumber/blob/master/lib/parallel_cucumber/runner.rb#L69